# doAfterSuccessOrError and doOnSuccess not called in order if there is intermediate operators

Tags: project-reactor

I'm using reactor-core 3.2.10.RELEASE. By default the `doAfterSuccessOrError` should be called after `doOnSuccess` called. But if I add `then` or `publishOn` operators it seems that it creates an inner Mono and the order of the doXXX changes.

Is  this an intended behavior?

```java
    Mono.just(1)
      .doAfterTerminate(() -> System.out.println("Terminated"))
      .doAfterSuccessOrError((i, e) -> System.out.println("AfterSuccessOrError: " + i))
      // Uncommenting any of these will change the order to
      //      .then(Mono.empty())
      //      .then()
      //      .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
      .doFinally(s -> System.out.println("Finally called"))
      .doOnSuccess(s -> System.out.println("Success"))
      .subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Result: " + i));
```

Expected output:

```
Success
Result: 1
AfterSuccessOrError: 1
Terminated
Finally called
```

After uncommenting `then` or `publishOn` the order changes.

```
AfterSuccessOrError: 1
Terminated
Success
Result: 1
Finally called
```

Comment: This issue might interest you: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1752

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an intended behavior?

Yes. [As per the docs for `then():](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-)

> Let this Mono complete then play another Mono.

...so in this case, it's because the `Mono` up until that point completes (hence the first two operators print), and then the output from your next `Mono` prints (the final 3 operators).

For [`publishOn()`, it's slightly different](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#publishOn-reactor.core.scheduler.Scheduler-):

> This operator influences the threading context where the rest of the operators in the chain *below it* will execute, up to a new occurrence of publishOn.

This means that you have your first two operators executing on one thread, and then the rest of your operators executing on a separate thread (defined by the elastic scheduler) - which is why you see the output. The mechanism is different here, but the end result happens to be exactly the same.